# Winforms crash without qtcore4.dll on win 7

Tags: c#, winforms, qt, windows-7

I'm writing a Windows Form Application, that makes extensive use of datagridview and others .net components. When I run the application on a Win 7, it always crashes, saying the qtcore4.dll library is missing.
My question is: is this a normal behaviour? and this is happening only to me? and what does that library do?

Comment: `qtcore4.dll` is not a .NET framework component. It is a 3rd party UI library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see where on disk it's trying to load `qtcore4.dll`.

Then make sure you have a copy of that .dll installed on disk in that location.

Otherwise, you may need to start shipping it with your application in the same directory as the run-time executable.

Answer (score 1):

Load the application into [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which will show you which other dll is trying to use it -- assuming it is not loaded via `LoadLibrary()`, in which case Mike's suggestion of using Process Monitor will be more useful